# kpm restore doesn't do anything in beta3

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have project with asp.net 5 beta 3. I am just trying to run it on a new machine. I installed the kvm successfully. `kvm list` and `kvm upgrade` commands work okay. `kpm restore` and `k web` commands are not wotking at all. No errors are displayed, the commands just don't do anything.

Here is how my command line looks like.

```
C:\Websites\aspnet5\web\approot\src\ProjectName>kpm restore

C:\Websites\aspnet5\web\approot\src\ProjectName>
```

Comment: `set KRE_TRACE=1`, but you should upgrade to `beta5`

Comment: Can I run a website using dnvm which was developed and published using kvm ?

Comment: Trace says "failed to load k" ?

Comment: try `kvm use default`

Comment: no, you can't run a `beta3` website with highter version

Comment: Make sure you have .NET 4.5.1 installed

Comment: `kvm use default` adds the path of bin folder to PATH variable. But output of `kpm restore` still the same. .net framework 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 definitely installed.